# Handling assertion in python

Tags: python, exception, assert

I can't understand why this code:

```
x='aaaa'
try: 
    self.assertTrue(x==y)
except: 
    print (x)
```

generates me this error

```
AssertionError: False is not True
```

It should be handle it by

```
print(x)
```

**EDIT**

original code is:

```
try:
    self.assertTrue('aaaa'==self.compare_object_name[1])
except:
    print ('aaa')
```

@Space_C0wb0y I can't give you full code because it is not my code, and I don't have a permission.

Comment: This looks like it is from a unit-test? Why would you want to catch such an assertion? Also, is this your original code? There was a syntax error in it, and also the indentation is weird. Please show us actual code that reproduces the be behavior.

Answer (score 4):

You should include the code that defines the `assertTrue` method. From the output you get, I'd say that it actually does not throw an exception, but deals with it internally (thus the error message being printed, and not your value).

You can use the built-in [`assert`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) statement of Python, which works as expected:

```
x = 'aaaa'
y = 'bbb'

try:
    assert(x == y)
except:
    print (x)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
aaaa
```

Comment: `assert` is a *statement*, not a method.

Comment: Be careful with the assert statement... if you ever compile your code with the `-O` (or `-OO`) option, they all disappear (by design).  See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement).